# com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception:

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, database-connection

i have a java system application which connects to a MySQL server hosted on bigRock , the application is working fine when i try to retrieve data from the database but on insertion it shows the following error.

```
SEVERE: null
com.mysql.jdbc.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure due to underlying exception: 

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.net.SocketException
MESSAGE: Connection reset by peer: socket write error

STACKTRACE:

java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
```

My connection class looks like

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc;

public class DataBaseFunctionting 
{
Connection conn =null;
PreparedStatement preparedStatement=null;
boolean reachable ;


private void connectionCheck()   // checks wether client is connected to the internet and host is reachable
{ 
     Socket socket = null;
 reachable = false;
   try
   {
    socket = new Socket("www.rinchedmurtipujaksang.com", 80);
    reachable = true;
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException ex) 
    {            
        Logger.getLogger(addNewArea.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    catch (IOException ex) 
    {
        Logger.getLogger(addNewArea.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }  

finally 
   {            
    if (socket != null) try { socket.close(); } catch(IOException e) {}
   }
 }  


public Connection connect()
{

     connectionCheck();
         if(!reachable)
         {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Unable to reaach the Server.\nCheck your internet connection OR contact host.");
             return null;
         }


   try 
   {
        String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://rinchedmurtipujaksang.com:3306/rin*******a";
        String username ="rinc*******min";
        String password = "****";

        conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");            
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, username, password);
        return conn;
     }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
         Logger.getLogger(DataBaseFunctionting.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
         System.out.println("Error : "+e);
         return null;
    }

}

public void disconnect() throws SQLException
{
     conn.close();
}


}
```

and the function which inserts the data from then frontend to the database looks like

```
public void addMemberToDB()
{
   try 
   {
       DB=new DataBaseFunctionting();
       con=DB.connect();
       PreparedStatement preparedstatement=con.prepareStatement("insert into Member values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

       preparedstatement.setObject(1,memberID);
       preparedstatement.setObject(2,familyIDBox.getText());
       preparedstatement.setObject(3,FName.getText());
       preparedstatement.setObject(4,MName.getText());
       preparedstatement.setObject(5,LName.getText());
       preparedstatement.setObject(6,FName.getText()+" "+MName.getText()+" "+LName.getText());
       if(male.isSelected())
       {
           preparedstatement.setObject(7,"Male");
       }
       else preparedstatement.setObject(7,"Female");

       preparedstatement.setObject(9,new DateTime(DOB.getDate()).toString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

       preparedstatement.setObject(8,livingStatus.getSelectedItem());
       if(livingStatus.getSelectedIndex()==1) 
        {
            DateTime dateTime=new DateTime(DOD.getDate());
            preparedstatement.setObject(10,dateTime.toString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
        }
        else preparedstatement.setObject(10,null);

       preparedstatement.setObject(11,workProfile.getText());
       if(RelationshipStatus.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Single"))
       {
           preparedstatement.setObject(12,0);
       }
       else preparedstatement.setObject(12,couple_id.getText());  // fix couple table if married.

       if(noNo.isSelected())
       {
           preparedstatement.setObject(13,null);
       }
       else preparedstatement.setObject(13,pNo.getText());

       if(noImage.isSelected())
       {
           preparedstatement.setBytes(14,null);
       }
       else
       {
            int s=0;
            byte[] imageData;  
            File image;
            image = new File(photoUrl.getText());
            FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(image);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] buff=new byte[1024];
            for(int readNum;(readNum=fis.read(buff))!=-1;)
            {
                bos.write(buff,0,readNum);
            }
            imageData=bos.toByteArray();
            preparedstatement.setBytes(14,imageData);
       }

       preparedstatement.setObject(15,fbUrl.getText());
       System.out.println(preparedstatement);
       preparedstatement.executeUpdate();
       DB.disconnect();


   }
   catch (SQLException | FileNotFoundException ex) 
   {
       Logger.getLogger(newMember.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   } catch (IOException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(newMember.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }

}
```

Can anyone help me get me rid of this error ?

Comment: Hi I am facing the same error  .Were you able to resolve it?